# How to push multiple docker images to docker hub?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I use docker locally (on Mac), I create several docker containers that can talk to each other. Now, wanting to push these images to docker hub, since each push is in a different repository, I'm confused how to replicate that inter-container communication. These images on docker hub no longer talk to each other.

So, if I have three local (working) images whose tags I modified as below for docker hub:

```
REPOSITORY               TAG
testingacct/testapp      services
testingacct/mysql        services
testingacct/tomcat       services
```

How do I push them to docker hub so the containers still talk to each other as they do locally?

Does the Java code itself need to be modified to use these paths instead of the working paths (from the docker-compose file) locally?

--

When I try to modify my docker-compose file from this (portion):

```
db:
      image: mysql:5.7
      container_name: test-mysql-docker
      ports:
           - 3307:3306
      volumes:
       - ./ZipCodeLookup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ZipCodeLookup.sql
      environment:
           MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "thepass"
```

to this:

```
db:
      image: testdockerhub/mysql:5.7
      container_name: test-mysql-docker
      ports:
           - 3307:3306
      volumes:
       - ./ZipCodeLookup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ZipCodeLookup.sql
      environment:
           MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "thepass"
```

I get: "ERROR: manifest for testdockerhub/mysql:5.7 not found"

--

Thanks,

Comment: A docker image is not like a folder of code. Link and network are for the containers. You need to check these fundamental notions

Comment: Could you share the set of `docker run` commands you're using (or the `docker-compose.yml` file), and what error you're getting?

Comment: I updated the problem statement above. Thanks.